# How to make transition background?

Tags: html, css

I uploaded a photo with a transition background on my website

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgdyi.jpg)

but there is not the right transition with the background of the page.

Is there any way how to make it?

Code:

```
<section class="intro clearfix" style="background-color:#dadada;);">
<div class="container clearfix" style="background-image: url('https://domain-name.com/')">
    <div class="intro-text">
        <h2 style="color:#3d3e3d">Choose Your Everyday Hairstyle</h2>
        <p style="color:#4c4f4d">Build your own image. Become more attractive.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've got some spare characters in your css: `);`

Comment: So, just to clarify, you're asking how you can **blend** the background with the image? If that's the case, you'll need to link to the problematic image in question, so we can download it and check which exact colours it's using.

Comment: Might be due to the background gradient image not filling the full width. Adding `background-size: cover` to the gradient background might do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I need blend the background with the image. So there isnt any way how to do it via CSS? I have to adjust the background of the image?

Comment: You could create a linear gradient that matches the gradient in the image, but that might be hard to match exactly. The easier solution would be to create a 1px vertical slice of the gradient at the edge of your image, then use that as a repeating background image behind the image.

Comment: I thought the picture editing would be the easiest way. But the image uses a different gradient over the entire area so I do not know how to grab it. Maybe its a question for designer right know